# R Shiny App that saves inputs for later use

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a Shiny app that will have many user inputs and so I would like to have an option that allows the user to save their inputs and load them back in for later use.  I was able to do this following an example I found online, but now I would like to ask for some help with altering the code functionality.  Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)  

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  br(),

  actionButton("load_inputs", "Load inputs"),
  br(),
  br(),

  numericInput("n", "Number",min = 1, value = 5),
  numericInput("upper", "Upper",min = 0, max = 100, value = 15),
  numericInput("lower", "Lower",min = 0, max = 100, value = 5),

  actionButton('save_inputs', 'Save inputs')

)) 

server <-  shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 

  switch(Sys.info()[['sysname']],
        Windows= {setwd(file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),"Desktop",fsep="\\"))},
        Mac = {  setwd("~/Desktop/")})

  observeEvent(input$load_inputs,{   

    if(!file.exists('inputs.RDS')) {return(NULL)}

    savedInputs <- readRDS('inputs.RDS')

    inputIDs      <- names(savedInputs) 
    inputvalues   <- unlist(savedInputs) 
    for (i in 1:length(savedInputs)) { 
      session$sendInputMessage(inputIDs[i],  list(value=inputvalues[[i]]) )
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$save_inputs,{ 
    saveRDS( reactiveValuesToList(input) , file = 'inputs.RDS')
  })  
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Now, rather than saving the file as a .RDS object, I would like to save the file as a .csv file that way the user who is not savvy in R can actually read the file and update it later if they want.  So I would like for the input to be saved as a .csv file in the following format (with example values):

```
n, 5
lower,10
upper, 29
```

if easier to manipulate in R it could also be formatted as

```
n, lower, upper
5, 10, 29
```

Lastly, when loading the file, it would be nice for the app to ask the user to point to the file location, and then when saving the inputs for the app to ask the user what location to save the file to.

How can I edit my code to achieve that?

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

Comment: @Carl I prefer to point people to the original source of the article at http://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/ because it has some updates that the RStudio version doesn't have

Comment: Sorry I didn't know it was double posted on the interwebs

Comment: I wonder if you could just use this instead. http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html. `shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")` All they have to do is bookmark the page to maintain their settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(shiny)  

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  textInput(inputId = 'inputsLocation', label = 'Inputs Location', value = "~/Desktop/user_inputs.csv"),
  actionButton('load_inputs', 'Load inputs'),
  br(),
  br(),
  numericInput("n", "Number",min = 1, value = 5),
  numericInput("upper", "Upper",min = 0, max = 100, value = 15),
  numericInput("lower", "Lower",min = 0, max = 100, value = 5),
  actionButton('save_inputs', 'Save inputs')

)) 

server <-  shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$load_inputs, {
    # Load inputs
    uploaded_inputs <- read.csv(input$inputsLocation)
    # Update each input
    for(i in 1:nrow(uploaded_inputs)){
      updateNumericInput(session,
                         inputId = uploaded_inputs$inputId[i],
                         value = uploaded_inputs$value[i])
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$save_inputs, {
    # Define inputs to save
    inputs_to_save <- c('n', 'upper', 'lower')
    # Declare inputs
    inputs <- NULL
    # Append all inputs before saving to folder
    for(input.i in inputs_to_save){
      inputs <- append(inputs, input[[input.i]])
    }
    # Inputs data.frame
    inputs_data_frame <- data.frame(inputId = inputs_to_save, value = inputs)
    # Save Inputs
    write.csv(inputs_data_frame, file = input$inputsLocation, row.names = FALSE)
  }) 

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

The data "user_inputs.csv" looks like this:

```
"inputId","value"
"n",5
"upper",7
"lower",4
```

I added column names "inputId" and "value" so the code can be more explicit.

The code is altered from your original post. To use a .csv file requires a different way of loading/saving inputs. I think this way is a simple way to do that is relatively easy to follow.

Note* When manually typing in the file path input, the user needs to either use double slashes "\\" or backslashes "/" in the file path (same as in R).

Comment: I have a quick question @easports611 : your code works perfectly when I use it in a separate R file and change the input fields. However, it bugs out when I include it in my module. My inputs ID is a little different : ns('project_id') instead of just 'project_id' , if it is the issue, is there a way around it?